# Future time travel in Terminator movies

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator, the-terminator-series, skynet

Something that I noticed about Terminator Genisys is that the time displacement technology designed by Skynet can send people to the future.  In all previous Terminator movies, they only travel to the past, as far as I can tell.  But in Genisys, they go from 1984 to 2017.

Did the machines always have the ability to send people to the future?  Is there any evidence in the prior movies or in other media that Skynet had ever used its time displacement technology to visit the future?  (Maybe to bring back more advanced technology from the future or to see the consequences of its decisions?) Or is this purely a Genisys development?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something similar happened in *Terminator: Sarah Connor Chronicles*. At multiple times in the show time displacement equipment was used to send people to the future.

So no, it's not the first time in the franchise that someone has time traveled forwards instead of the traditional time travel backwards.